# extJs access a parent function from nested object

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to acess a function of parent object from inside of a nested object.

```
Ext.define('SearchPanel', {
    extend: 'common.Panel',
    header: false,
    xtype: 'search-panel',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form-panel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'datetimefield',
                    itemId: 'from',
                    fieldLabel: T('From'),
                    dateConfig: {
                        itemId: 'startDate',
                        value: new Date(),
                        validator: ValidateRange//trying to access "external" function here
                    },
                    timeConfig: {
                        value: '12:00 AM',
                        itemId: 'startTime',
                        validator: ValidateRange//trying to access "external" function here
                    }
                }
            ],
            ValidateRange: //the function I'm trying to call from nested object
            function (value) {
                //validation logic
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

It doesn't work. I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: ValidateRange is not defined

Comment: try with this this.up().up(). ValidateRange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, you have to use a method defined outside the class. Our you could use a static member and reference this:

```
Ext.define('SearchPanel', {
    statics: {
         validateRange: function() {}
    },
    items: {
        someRandomChild: {
            validator: function() {
                return SearchPanel.validateRange.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You have to wrap it into another function cause the `SearchPanel` is not defined when the class is "defined" by ExtJS.

Answer (score 1):

Methods defined outside the class can be made globally accessible by appending them to `window` object.

```
var externalFunc = function() {
    //some logic
};

window.AccessingExternalFunc = externalFunc;
```

`externalFunc` is now available at `window.AccessingExternalFunc`.